# Как запустить Flask через https без лишней боли?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

Вот у меня такой код:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "<h1>Hello!</h1>"


def create_app():
   return app
```

Далее, я использовал `waitress-serve --port=8080 --host=xx.xx.xx.xx --call hello:create_app`

Все бы было хорошо, пока я не поставил nginx, который просто выдает приветствие "Привет, я nginx!" , а при указании директории приложения, 403 - Forbidden.

Пытался прописывать переадресацию в `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, все бесполезно.

На порту 80, естественно, приложение не запустить, он занят nginx'ом.

Делал по мануалу из интернетика. Как решить эту проблему - не нашел. Хелп плз.

Comment: Как конкретно пытались прописывать переадресацию и что конкретно с ней было не так?

Comment: Хотя бы так:  proxy_pass http://unix:/home/flask/flaskapp/flaskapp.sock;
При перезапуске hginx ошибку не выдал, но все бесполезно.

Comment: Ну а этот самый /home/flask/flaskapp/flaskapp.sock у вас вообще существует?

Comment: Зачем задаете лишние вопросы, если не знаете, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: То, что вы уклонились от ответа, намекает на то, что вы бездумно копируете буковки из мануалов, не прикладывая никаких усилий, чтобы понять, что вы вообще делаете и зачем эти буковки нужны. Это очень грустно, с таким подходом вам заниматься программированием не стоит

Comment: То, что я "уклонился" от ответа говорит о том, что я зря теряю с вами время. Я все сказал.

Comment: А могли бы за эти почти три дня уже озаботиться созданием этого самого /home/flask/flaskapp/flaskapp.sock